# create dict combining two other dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the best way to create a dict from two other dicts (very big one and small one)?

We have:

```
    big_dict = {
    'key1':325,
    'key2':326,
    'key3':327,
    ...
    }

    small_dict = {
    325:0.698,
    326:0.684,
    327:0.668
    }
```

Needs to get a dict for data in small_dict, but we should use keys from big_dict:

```
    comb_dict = {
    'key1':0.698,
    'key2':0.684,
    'key3':0.668
    }
```

Comment: What should happen if the value from `big_dict` isn't a key in `small_dict`?

Comment: It is a good point. But in this practical task both dicts came from one function (TfidfVectorizer()). So in this case there are values in big_dict for each key of small_dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works with all cases (example shown in the driver values), with a more [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) oriented approach.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for key,val in big_dict.items(): 
        try: 
            d[key] = small_dict[val] 
        except KeyError: 
            continue

=> {'key1': 0.698, 'key2': 0.684, 'key3': 0.668}
```

#driver values :

```
IN : big_dict = {
        'key1':325,
        'key2':326,
        'key3':327,
        'key4':330        #note that small_dict[330] will give KeyError
     }

IN : small_dict = {
          325:0.698,
          326:0.684,
          327:0.668
      }
```

Or, using `Dictionary Comprehension` :

```
>>> {key:small_dict[val] for key,val in big_dict.items() if val in small_dict}

=> {'key1': 0.698, 'key2': 0.684, 'key3': 0.668}
```

Comment: `d[key] = small_dict[val]` should probably be `d[key] = deepcopy(small_dict[val])`. If small_dict's cal is not an immutable object (string, int, ect...) if down the line `d[key]` is changed with a append() (if it is a list) or any other object specific method it will have the side effect of changing `small_dict`. Also if deepcopy() is called on an immutable object there is almost no performance loss. Python will still keep the memory reference just like a normal `=` would.

Answer (score 1):

You could use dictionary comprehension:

```
comb_dict = {k: small_dict[v] for k, v in big_dict.iteritems()}
```

If `big_dict` may contain values that are not keys in `small_dict` you could just ignore them:

```
comb_dict = {k: small_dict[v] for k, v in big_dict.iteritems() if v in small_dict}
```

or use the original value:

```
{k: (small_dict[v] if v in small_dict else v) for k, v in big_dict.iteritems()}
```

(Use `items()` in Python3)

Comment: Comprehensions are cool, but they're a little hard to read sometimes. Especially the last example here with the ternary expression--you probably wouldn't want to do that in production code.

Comment: @Wyatt I agree about the ternary expression, I added it for completeness. I added parentheses to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If there are values in `big_dict` that may not be present as keys in `small_dict`, this will work:

```
combined_dict = {}
for big_key, small_key in big_dict.items():
    combined_dict[big_key] = small_dict.get(small_key)
```

Or you might want to use a different default value instead with:

```
    combined_dict[big_key] = small_dict.get(small_key, default='XXX')
```

Or you might want to raise a `KeyError` to indicate a problem with your data:

```
    combined_dict[big_key] = small_dict[small_key]
```

Or you might want to skip missing keys:

```
    if small_key in small_dict:
        combined_dict[big_key] = small_dict[small_key]
```

Comment: The one problem with that is if `small_dict[small_key]` has a value that is a complex object (dict, list, ect...) when you do `combined_dict[big_key] = small_dict[small_key]` you will be giving the combined_dict a pointer to the small_dicts data. So if you ever change the combined_dict data it will change it in the small_dict as well. A simple `deepcopy()` on the value set would fix it.

Comment: @PeterH That's a good point, but I couldn't address all possible scenarios ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = small_dict.keys()
combined_dict = {k:small_dict[v] for k,v in big_dict.items() if v in keys}
>>> combined_dict
{'key3': 0.668, 'key2': 0.684, 'key1': 0.698}
```